# How to change one specific CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have a problem where I've developed a website through Wordpress, and want to style all the product prices one way, and the subtotal, tax and total another way. They're all in a CSS class as woocommerce-Price-amount amount. Is there anyway I can only target the ones that are inside the tr "cart_item"? Thank you!

```
 <table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table" style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<thead style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    <tr>
        <th class="product-name" style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Product</th>
        <th class="product-total" style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Total</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
                        <tr class="cart_item">
                    <td class="product-name" style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                        Autumn Leaf Shirt - Large&nbsp;                          <strong class="product-quantity">× 2</strong>                                                  </td>
                    <td class="product-total" style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>70.00</span>                       </td>
                </tr>
                    </tbody>
<tfoot>

    <tr class="cart-subtotal">
        <th style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Subtotal</th>
        <td style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>70.00</span></td>
    </tr>




                                <tr class="tax-total">
                <th style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Tax</th>
                <td style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>0.00</span></td>
            </tr>


    <tr class="order-total">
        <th style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Total</th>
        <td style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>70.00</span></strong> </td>
    </tr>


</tfoot>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can specifically target the `woocommerce-price-item` inside `cart_item` as:

`.cart_item .woocommerce-Price-amount{
   /**Your Properties here**/
}`

This will only apply your properties to elements with class `woocommerce-Price-amount` inside elements with class `cart_item`

Basically in CSS, you can access `bar` inside `foo` as:

`.foo .bar{
}`